# Facebook Graph API, Hackbook, iOS - how to query friends birthdays

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm learning to integrate Facebook into my next iOS app, and currently using their own sample project Hackbook, which is a great demonstration of the different API calls, requests, permissions and such.

I am able to get the extended permission to get friends_birthday, and verified using my Facebook account that the app has permission.  I am also able to pull MY birthday using Hackbooks apiGraphMe method, and display it under Basic Information, however, I cannot seem to modify Hackbooks getUserFriends method to display their birthdays like I can for myself.

Has anyone modified Hackbook before learning the API and pulled a friends birthday?  If not I hope someone has experience with it.  Mind you I'd like to see it done with the Hackbook project format as that's the tool I'm learning on.

Thanks in advance, I'll be sure to accept fast!

```
- (IBAction) getPublicInfo: (id)sender {
                       NSMutableDictionary * params = [NSMutableDictionary    
                   dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  @"SELECT uid,name FROM user WHERE uid=4", @"query",
                                  nil];
                     [_facebook requestWithMethodName: @"fql.query"
                         andParams: params
                     andHttpMethod: @"POST"
                       andDelegate: self];
```

Comment: Do you know how to make FQL queries from Hackbook already? Because using FQL it’s quite easy.

Comment: Ughhhh posting code on my iPad is terrible, I'll fix on my Mac then, but does this look like the right way to do an fql query?

Comment: No need, I fixed it for you! :)

Comment: No comment, but a vote down, thanks, I'm just trying to get help, no chastised.  Appreciate it everyone else.

Comment: Thanks Moxy, looks like I'm in the right ballpark, let me try it out, and I'll be sure to accept your answer, just want to make sure I post how I did it in Hackbook so others can see how it's done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the FQL query :

```
select uid,name,birthday_date from user where uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1=me())
```

Don't forget the permission `friends_birthday` !

Comment: Ok definitely works, USING HACKBOOK, ive successfully pulled a random friend into the main menu, and listed their birthday, this answer is correct, now i can finally move on with my life, thanks for taking the time to humor me Moxy.  Accepted  if anyone needs help with this message me!

Comment: @theProject: i want need your help i stuck on that task

Comment: sure, pm me whats troubling you msb!